# Spinner JavaFx как узнать текущее значение

Tags: java, javafx

С помощью spinner хочу узнать значение переменной заданной пользователем, но подобная реализация не работает,
FXML:

```
...

<Spinner fx:id="spinner1" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="251.0" initialValue="12 " min="2" max="100000" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="266.0">
                    <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets />
                    </opaqueInsets></Spinner>
...
```

Controller:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
...
    @FXML
    Spinner spinner1 = new Spinner();

    int value = spinner1.getValue();
...
```

Как осуществить подобное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы переинициализировали `spinner1` и потеряли ссылку на объект на форме. Нужно примерно так:

```
@FXML
Spinner spinner1;

int value = spinner1.getValue();
```